# Perform a Put on byte array in to a Active Directory attribute

Tags: c++, com, active-directory

I am attempting to perform a [`Put`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a `Octet String` attribute of a directory entry, I am trying to load a byte array (actually it is a [`DATA_BLOB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if it makes a difference). However any examples I have seen about performing a `Put` only show how to load strings or single values (like a int, or bool), I can't find anything on how to load a byte array in to a directory entry.

What I have done so far:

```
DATA_BLOB secureBlob = //...

VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);

V_ARRAY(&var) = //??????
V_VT(&var) = VT_ARRAY;

userObject->Put(CComBSTR("vwSecureBlob"), var);

VariantClear(&var);
LocalFree(secureBlob.pbData);
```

I could just assign `secureBlob.pbData` to `V_ARRAY(&var)` but how do I tell the variant the size of the array?

---

I have heard things about using a [`SAFEARRAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I have yet to see any examples of how to use it that I could understand.

Comment: I think what you need to do is to do a SAFEARRAY, you could also take a look at CComVariant to get a more convenient way of handling VARIANTs.

Comment: +1 for SAVEARRAY VT_ARRAY|VT_BYTE is what you need I think. I also reccommend _variant_t and _bstr_t over ATL - comes with the SDK you don't need to pay for Visual Studio.

Comment: @AndersK Can you post a an answer showing how to use a SAFEARRAY?

Comment: @Ben Can you show how to translate my CComBSTR call in to a _bstr_t call and show how to implement the SAVEARRAY solution?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I will try to dig one out - I did this a while ago.